# how do I open the console like this

Tags: c++

[image]

I learn programming in codecademy, and they have a simulator with the console on the right side like this.

When I want to compile and run programs, I type `g++ mycpp anothercpp` then run in with second command `./a.out`

Can I open this console in the actual c++?

Comment: Are you asking about a feature of a web site? Or do you want to just open a console window on your OS and compile from there? On linux or macOS you probably already have the tools installed. On windows you won't but msys2 is a good option

Comment: I want to open this console on the windows 10 like Ayxan has answered for me.

Comment: from what I can see on the screenshot, that seems like a bash shell... you could try reading the following article on enabling linux bash shells on windows 10: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a compiler. You seem to be using Windows. On Windows, it's easy to install [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler. Once you do it, you'll be able to do something similar:

[image: powershell]

Comment: hey thanks, another question, is there any risk if I mistyped using this console on my windows ? Would it mess up my system or something. I  use this console just because I don't know how to link 2 or more cpp. in normal C++ into one.

Comment: ***I don't know how to link 2 or more cpp. in normal C++ into one*** If you are talking about VSCode, the documentation tells you how to modify `tasks.json` to build more than 1 file into an executable.

Comment: @Khang If you misspell the file names it will just warn you that such a file doesn't exist.